# PHP 7.2-FPM error

Tags: server, 18.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

Honestly this is so frustrating . I don't know what am i doing wrong.

I want to set up a virtual host/service block. When I browse `www.example.com`, it should show me `This is a test page www.example.com`!

**UPDATE : I GET THIS ERROR in nginx error log file:**

```
11:40:52 [crit] 12959#12959: *9 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed
```

I created a file in `/var/www/www.example.com/index.php`:

```
<?php

echo "<h1> This is a test page www.example.com ! </h1>";
```

Then under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com`:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/www.example.com;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com  www.example.com;

        location / {
               # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Then under `/etc/sites-enabled/www.example.com` (same code as as `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com`):

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/www.example.com;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com  www.example.com;

        location / {
               # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

I have also run `nginx -t` and restarted my nginx.

When I browse to `www.example.com`, it takes to some other website. Basically `index.php` does not get reflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem:

Basically we should edit the `www.conf` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

You should comment out this line by adding `;` at the beginning of the line.

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

And uncomment this line:

```
listen =/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

Now when you run `sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`, the error should no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

> When I browse to www.example.com"

You own www.example.com?

> When I browse www.example.com , it should show me This is a test page www.example.com !

No not really. Unless the owner of www.example.com is you. And I seriously doubt that since it is an "IANA-managed Reserved Domains". You are supposed to change it to your domain and if you do not own a domain to an IP address (or localhost).

Comment: oh ok . In summary any other domain name besides www.example.com right ?

Comment: No, you can not pick a random domain.  You change it to a domain you bought or to an external IP address. Or an internal IP or to localhost if you host it only in your network.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue , when I used  test1.com for an html site, it runs fine. I think the php7.2-fpm has error. When I run sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log
, it gives me 12959#12959: *9 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Comment: That is a different issue. The manual https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04 states "Your configuration may differ somewhat. Look for a block beginning with location `~ \.php$ {`, and a line that looks something like `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`. Change this to use `unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`"   Why does yours lack `/var`?

Comment: Hey man, u are a genius, it works, but I did some tweaking i will post my solution above. SO that if anyone faces problem can refer to that

Comment: No no! add it as an answer and we can upvote the answer :D Ill remove mine when you are done. Glad you got it working! :)